# quarantining in the UK pending negative COVID-19 PCR test results

Tags: uk, covid-19, quarantine

Normally when I travel to the UK from the US I'll take the tube to my hotel. According to https://www.gov.uk/guidance/how-to-quarantine-when-you-arrive-in-england#new-rules-for-fully-vaccinated-arrivals however, you'll need to quarantine until you get the test results.

If I could get tested at the airport (Heathrow) and get a negative result within an hour or so that wouldn't be too disruptive to my routine but I'm not seeing anything like that on the scheduling website.

Skimming over the test providers a lot of them let you self swab but you have to snail mail your results, so it could very well be *days* before you get your results back. So how are you supposed to get to the hotel while awaiting the results? Can I do the tube or do I need to do a taxi?

Also, what about food? The hotel I usually stay at doesn't have room service. I guess I'll just have to do Uber Eats or whatever until I get the test results back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Further down the page you link to it states:

**How to travel to the place where you’re quarantining**

When you arrive in England, go straight to the place you’re staying to quarantine. Only use public transport if you have no other option, and make sure you follow safer travel guidance for passengers https://www.gov.uk/guidance/coronavirus-covid-19-safer-travel-guidance-for-passengers

So yes, you can take the Tube or a taxi to your hotel.

You will either have to take sufficient food and other necessities with you, or you can have them delivered (as stated further down again on the page you link to). You must not use shared areas such as bars, restaurants, health clubs and sports facilities.